# Opening a dynamic page within a jQuery dialog, adding a back button

Tags: jquery, dialog

A jQuery noob here. I’m currently working on a project with a clickable `map` and jQuery `dialogs`. Here’s the rundown:

*1) An image map in which every area is a clickable hotspot.*

*2) Upon clicking on any of those hotspots, a dynamic page with a list of services related to that place opens in a jQuery dialog. The dynamic page is a PHP page which connects to a database.*

*3) Upon clicking on any of the services in the list, another dynamic page with information on that service will open in the dialog. The dynamic page will once again be a PHP page which connects to a database.*

Now, in the service view (part 3), **I’d like to add a ”back” button on the fly which would take the user back to the list of services**. But in the service list this button should be hidden. How should I implement this?

Another problem with my code is that **if the user clicks on a place in the map and then clicks on another place without closing the dialog first, the links the service list will stop working**. I have circumvented this by making the dialog modal which forces the user to close the dialog before interacting with the map again, but for integrity’s sake, **how would I make it work on a non-modal dialog?**

Here’s a dumbed down version of my code (map replaced with a list).

**map.php (with jQuery):**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".opencategory").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#popup").load("category.php",{
             categoryid: $(this).data("categoryid") }, 
             function() {
                $("#popup").dialog("open");
             });
        });

    $("#popup").dialog( {
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        buttons: [ {
            text: "Back",
            click: function() {
                // ???
            }
        }, {
            text: "Close",
            click: function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        } ],
        open: function() {
            $(".openservice").click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $("#popup").load("service.php", { 
                    serviceid: $(this).data("serviceid") 
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
<body>

<ol>
<li><a href="#" data-categoryid="1" class="opencategory">Category 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-categoryid="2" class="opencategory">Category 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-categoryid="3" class="opencategory">Category 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-categoryid="4" class="opencategory">Category 4</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-categoryid="5" class="opencategory">Category 5</a></li>
</ol>

<div id="popup"></div>    
</body>
```

**category.php:**

```
<?php $categoryid = $_POST["categoryid"]; ?>

<p>Services of category <?php echo $categoryid ?>:</p>
<ul>
<li><a href="#" data-serviceid="1" class="openservice">Service 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-serviceid="2" class="openservice">Service 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-serviceid="3" class="openservice">Service 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-serviceid="4" class="openservice">Service 4</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-serviceid="5" class="openservice">Service 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

**service.php:**

```
<?php $serviceid = $_POST["serviceid"]; ?>

<p>Information of service <?php echo $serviceid ?></p>
```

Comment: For the second problem you could add an overlay behind the modal so it forces the user to close the dialog or overlay's `onclick` event closes it `lightbox` style

Comment: G.Mendes: Setting the dialog modal actually does force the user to close the dialog first and clears my second problem. I was just wondering if there’s something wrong with my code because the links stop working on a non-modal dialog. :)

About the ”Back” button, let me try to be clearer. Currently, if the user opens up the service view (part 3) and then wants to view another service from the same category, they’d have to close the dialog and navigate from the start again. With the back button, they’d be taken straight back to the service list.

Comment: thanks I get it now, how about using `load()` method again? have you tried? if so, what happened?

Comment: I was hoping there would be something similar to history.back() with dialogs, but thank you, using load() again does work. There was just a problem with sending the correct category id with the Back button click (as you can see, I have a data-categoryid attribute with the links, which I POST to the PHP script), but I got it sorted out. Now I just need to figure how to not NOT show the back button in the service list, but I think I can use .push() and .splice() to accomplish that.

Comment: you could also use back click event to hide itself, showing again after on the next page

Comment: @G.Mendes Could you give a code sample? Like I said, I’m a noob. :)


Oh, and I was too quick on my words the last time. The back button does work, but after clicking it the links in the service list won’t work anymore. I think the fact that I’m reusing the same dialog is messing things up?

Comment: the same way you added the buttons you can use the setter to reset them: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-buttons upon "back" `click` function that is commented as ??? in your code, if you could set up a http://jsfiddle.net/ simulating the problem would be easier for us to assist

Comment: Ok, now I’m getting the hang of it. Thanks again, @G.Mendes. Here’s a fiddle with my original code (`load()` replaced with `html()`): http://jsfiddle.net/VqraY/ The buttons work like I want now, I think, but the problem with the links persists. Click category -> click service -> click back -> links stop working.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I ended up doing it with two dialogs. The category dialog with the list of services only has a ”close” button, which does what it’s expected to do. The service dialog, which opens on top of the category dialog, has a ”back” and a ”close” button. ”Back” closes only the service dialog and reveals the category dialog under it, ”Close” closes both at once. In the service dialog I also had to change the behavior of the ”x” button to close both dialogs. The show and hide effects also took some fine-tuning.

I’m not very pleased with this solution, but I’m in a hurry, so it has to do for now. I’d be pleased to hear about better solutions.

**Here’s the updated map.php:**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".opencategory").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#category").dialog("option", "show", true);
        $("#category").dialog("option", "hide", true);
        $("#category").load("category.php", {
            categoryid: $(this).data("categoryid")
        }, function() {
            $("#category").dialog("open");
        });
    });

    $("#category").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        draggable: false,
        height: 500,
        width: 500,
        show: true,
        hide: true,
        closeText: "Close",
        buttons: [{
            text: "Close",
            click: function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }],
        open: function() {
            $("#category").find(".openservice").click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $("#service").load("service.php", {
                    serviceid: $(this).data("serviceid")
                }, function() {
                    $("#service").dialog("open");
                });
            });
        }
    });

    $("#service").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: false,
        resizable: false,
        draggable: false,
        height: 500,
        width: 500,
        show: true,
        hide: true,
        closeText: "Close",
        buttons: [{
            text: "Back",
            click: function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }, {
            text: "Close",
            click: function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                $("#category").dialog("option", "show", false);
                $("#category").dialog("option", "hide", false);
                $("#category").dialog("close");
            }
        }],
        open: function() {
            $(this).closest(".ui-dialog").find(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").click(function() {
                $("#category").dialog("option", "show", false);
                $("#category").dialog("option", "hide", false);
                $("#category").dialog("close");
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
<body>

<ul>
<li><a href="#" data-categoryid="1" class="opencategory">Category 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-categoryid="2" class="opencategory">Category 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-categoryid="3" class="opencategory">Category 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-categoryid="4" class="opencategory">Category 4</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-categoryid="5" class="opencategory">Category 5</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="category"></div>
<div id="service"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I realized I should probably post this as an answer instead of comment, so someone might actually see it.

See fiddle of my original idea, updated: http://jsfiddle.net/VqraY/1/

I managed to get the buttons working, but the problem with the service links persists. **Click a category → click a service → click back → links don’t work anymore. I think it’s because I’m declaring the `$(".openservice").click()` function in the open event of the dialog.** How to circumvent this problem? I could close the dialog in between and open it again right away, but that also fires the show and hide effects of the dialog and makes the screen blink because of the dimmed background of a modal dialog.